# .htaccess being ignored? Not redirecting like it's supposed to

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Okay I'm trying to use Lando (landocms.com) and I'm trying to get the pretty urls option to work.

Basically by default Lando creates link like: domain.com/index.php/page. Supposedly, there is a way to remove the index.php so the links become: domain.com/page. I have created an .htaccess as directed, however it does not work.

Here is the .htaccess I am using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
  RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-d 
  RewriteRule   ^(.*)$                index.php/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried alot of variations, /index.php/, index.php? and plenty more but none work. According to HostGator everything should be fine. Any thoughts? I think I'm going crazy haha.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that the .htaccess file is being read and that your web host allows .htaccess files? You can be certain it's being read by causing a syntax error -- just write `asdf` at the top of the file.

Comment: makesure file .htaccess in correct directory "/public_html/"

Comment: @JacobDalton Tried that, gives me a 500 error, so I guess it is being read.

Comment: @rusly I have public_html and then public_html/domainname where my site is. That is where I put the .htaccess for this site. When I put it in just public_html I got 500 errors on domain.com/page.

Comment: To start, why aren't you using the complete rule-set given by Lando in the link pointed out by @MikeAnthony? There are some directives missing that are important. Follow the Lando instructions, they know what they are talking about. Needless to say the incoming, entered, linked to, shown in the browser's address bar, should be this URL: `domain.com/page`, not this one `domain.com/index.php/page`.

Comment: EDIT - the site is viewable at [link](http://hyperstatik.com) so you can see what is going on.

Comment: @faa I was just about to reply to his post, I actually am using the provided .htaccess I just didn't want to copy the whole thing. But even using that doesn't work. And yes, but domain.com/page just shows the default home page.

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting for a CMS is a two-tier approach. First, you need to set your `.htaccess` (I have put a safer one here for you):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Then, LandoCMS allows you to remove the `index.php` from the generated addresses, by means of turning on the appropriate setting in the administration panel. See [this link](http://landocms.com/docs/pretty-urls/) for more information.

If the `.htaccess` content I've given you doesn't work, then simply use the one that the CMS has given you.

Comment: Thanks for this, however, I tried your .htaccess and it didn't change anything. :( And I currently am using the provided .htaccess, but it doesn't worth either. I have the seeting on to remove index.php from the links.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if this actually isn't an `.htaccess` problem... Everything is actually being routed, but I don't think LandoCMS is handling it properly.

Comment: Or it is... If I use the route with the `index.php`, it works... Which is weird.

Comment: Is your `htaccess` file in the same directory as Lando's index file?

Comment: @MikeAnthony I thought about it being an issue with the cms, but since it does actually work with index.php url, I don't think that could be it... (unless im missing something, I been trying this for hours l0l)

Comment: In your themes header, please enter `print var_dump(url_segments())`. I'd like to see if Lando is really parsing the URI properly.

Comment: I can't quite tell what is wrong with it, except that it is actually supposed to be throwing a 404 not found. I typed `index/posts/first-post` in, and it took me to the home page, which is why I believe it isn't handling the route properly. Best suggestion is to file an issue report on their Github page, or with them via email.

Comment: @MikeAnthony Hey Mike wish i could give you some more rep, I really appreciate the help. I'm just going to get in touch with them directly, and if it can't get sorted I'll have to find something else. Thanks though!

Comment: I see you have solved your problem. What did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the `index.php` part from any URL, but process the incoming, friendly URLs through `index.php` nevertheless

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php and redirect client
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SEO} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?index.php/(.*) /$1 [R,L]

# process friendly URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/
RewriteRule .+ /index.php/$0 [E=SEO:1,L]
```

The environment setting `E=SEO:1` prevents an endless loop.

Comment: Man this looks like it would totally make sense! Unfortunately, it too  does nothing. :/ Appreciate the help though!

Comment: @zakoll It works in the virtual host on my local machine. Maybe you have some apache setting, you haven't mentioned yet.

Comment: What are your vh host settings? I just found out my host was running php 5.2, so I upgraded to 5.3 (which caused a php on the pages to go away), however still no dice with the urls!

Comment: @zakoll This has nothing to do with PHP. This is only about Apache configuration.